# Copy 7000 rows in first loop and then next 7000 rows until range is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I need code which should first count how many times loop should be executed (suppose I have 18000 rows then 18000/7000 = 2.57 so 3 times), and then it should start a loop and copy first 7000 rows and paste in sheet2, and then the next 7000 rows (7001 to 14000) and this should continue until the range is empty.

I am referring to this code shown here, but it is not helping me out:

```
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long

c = GetTargetColumn() ' Or you could just set this manually, like: c = 1

With Sheet1 ' <-- You should always qualify a range with a sheet!

    For r = 1 To 7000 ' Or 1 To (Ubound(MyListOfStuff) + 1)

        ' Here we're looping over all the cells in rows 1 to 10, in Column "c"
        .Cells(r, c).Value = MyListOfStuff(r)

        '---- or ----

        '...to easily copy from one place to another (even with an offset of rows and columns)
        .Cells(r, c).Value = Sheet2.Cells(r + 3, 17).Value

    Next r

End With
```

Comment: Copying the contents of cells individually is very slow. Is there any reason why you are not using `Range(source).Copy(destination)`?

Comment: why should you divide loops in 7000 rows chunks?

Comment: Use `Step 7000` within a `For` loop

Comment: "this should continue until the range is empty." .... Also, you are starting with row 1 .. This means you are trying to copy the entire sheet? I would use "move or copy sheet" option instead of coping data from one sheet to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"This should continue until the range is empty." My code below copies the entire range but doesn't delete the original as your descriptions seems to imply. That should be quite easy, however, if required - just `WsS.Cells.ClearContents`added at the end.

Meanwhile, the code does what you describe. The number of rows to be copied in one loop can be set at the top of the procedure. I set `Const BlockRowCount As Long = 3`, doing 3 rows in a loop. It will also work for 7000 rows.

I noticed that your code doesn't seem to copy A1 to A1. `Const FirstTargetCell As String = "B3"` defines the top-left cell in the destination sheet as B3. You can specify any cell you want in that location and the code will hang the data from that peg.

```
Sub TransferData()

    Const BlockRowCount As Long = 3
    ' cell A1 from the source sheet will arrive at
    ' FirstTargetCell on the target sheet. All other data relative to it.
    Const FirstTargetCell As String = "B3"      ' modify as required

    Dim WsS As Worksheet                ' Source sheet
    Dim WsT As Worksheet                ' Target sheet
    Dim Src As Range                    ' source data range
    Dim Tgt As Range                    ' target data range
    Dim Arr As Variant                  ' data array
    Dim Rl As Long, Cl As Long          ' last used row / column
    Dim Ct As Long                      ' first Target column
    Dim Rs As Long, Rt As Long          ' source / target row
    Dim R As Long

    Set WsS = Worksheets("Source Data")
    Set WsT = Worksheets("Destination")
    With Range(FirstTargetCell)
        Rt = .Row
        Ct = .Column
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    With WsS
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Cl = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For Rs = 0 To Abs(Int(Rl / BlockRowCount * -1)) - 1
            R = Application.Min((Rs + 1) * BlockRowCount, Rl)
            Set Src = .Range(.Cells(Rs * BlockRowCount + 1, 1), _
                             .Cells(R, Cl))
            Arr = Src.Value
            With WsT
                Set Tgt = .Cells(Rt, Ct).Resize(UBound(Arr), UBound(Arr, 2))
                Tgt.Value = Arr
            End With
            Rt = Rt + BlockRowCount
        Next Rs
    End With

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```